# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0 not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have read all threads about this without finding any answer to my problem. I have tried with different connections string with no luck?

I have tried many things but I dont know what causes this? Has anyone had the same problem and found a solution?

First of this is my stack trace

**Stack Trace:**

```
[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.]
 System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5081160
 System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +132
 System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +64
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +150
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +59
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.CreateConnection(String connectionString) +34
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +117
 System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
 System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
 System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
 System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
 System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

**WEB CONFIG**

```
  <connectionStrings>
  <add name="riktigaconnstringen" connectionString="Data Source=aspx-XXXXX.mssql.binero.se;Initial Catalog=XXXX-aspx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXXX"/>
```

**AND MY PAGE**

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource 
        ID="test1" 
        runat="server" 
        DataSourceMode="DataSet"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM t_produkter"
        ConnectionString="<% ConnectionStrings:riktigaconnstringen %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem, but in the MSDN example for SqlDataSource I can see a different syntax for referencing the ConnectionString

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource
      ID="test1"   
      runat="server"   
      DataSourceMode="DataSet"  
      SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM t_produkter"  
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:riktigaconnstringen %>"></asp:SqlDataSource
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note the `$` char after the `<%`

Comment: It sure did! Thanks for helping me out of my blindness!!

Comment: hey, good one here. question, how can i put function on the sqldatasource. I have a function to encrypt/decrypt connectionstring. something like Decrypt(connString) .. I want to put Decrypt on sqldatasource, how can I do that? Check this link --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635657/decrypt-sqldatasource-from-codebehind-c-sharp ,,,Cheers,

Comment: @Haminteu You should post a new question.